# How to output partial of the result !da address with windbg?

Tags: debugging, windbg, sos

If the array  contains 100000000 item , it is too long to output all of the itemsm so may I know if I want to just output  ten items of the array with windbg, such as !da **top 10** address, how to deal with it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [sos](/questions/tagged/sos) `!da` command takes `-start` and `-length` parameter:

```
 -start <startIndex>: optional, only supported for single dimension array. 
                      Specify from which index the command shows the elements.
 -length <length>:    optional, only supported for single dimension array. 
                      Specify how many elements to show.
```

In [sosex](/questions/tagged/sosex) you can use `!mdt` with the `-start:` and `-count:` parameters:

```
!sosex.mdt [typename | paramname | localname | MT] [ADDR] 
           [-r[:level]] [-e[:level]] [-start:index] [-count:n]
```

Or you can use [NetExt](https://github.com/rodneyviana/netext). The [`!wdo`](https://github.com/rodneyviana/netext#wdo) command works for arrays and has `/start`  and `/end` parameters to limit the indices:

```
!wdo [/forcearray] [/shownull] [/noheader] [/noindex] [/mt <expr>]
     [/start <expr>] [/end <expr>] <expr>
  /mt <expr> - mt,Method table for value objects (space-delimited)
  <expr> - Address,Object Address
  /start <expr> - Starting index to show in an array (space-delimited)
  /end <expr> - Ending index to show in an array (space-delimited)
  /forcearray - For Byte[] and Char[] arrays show items not the string
  /shownull - For arrays will show items that are null
  /noheader - Display only object address and field and values
  /noindex - For arrays it will show values without the index
  /tokens - show class and type tokens for fields
```